# Как уничтожить Window

Tags: java, swing

Есть окно, при нажатии на кнопку окно должно закрыться и уничтожиться.
Как это сделать, зная что метод `Window.getOwnerlessWindows()` возвращает ссылки на все когда-либо созданные Window (в том числе и ссылку на уничтожаемое окно). Как тогда уничтожить `Window`?

Вот пример:

```
package javaapplication28;

import java.awt.Window;
import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class JavaApplication28 {


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //
        final JFrame frame = new JFrame("TEST");
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);



        //

        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(1000);
                } catch (InterruptedException ex) {}

                //КРУГ 1, УЗНАЕМ НАШИ ФРЕЙМЫ
                Window[] wind = Window.getOwnerlessWindows();

                int a = 0;
                int max = wind.length;


                System.out.println("Ссылки на фреймы до уничтожения");
                while(a!=max){
                    System.out.println(wind[a].getClass().getCanonicalName());
                    ((JFrame)wind[a]).setTitle(((JFrame)wind[a]).getTitle().concat(" КРУГ 1"));
                    a = a + 1;
                }
                //


                //ПЫТАЕМСЯ УБИТЬ
                frame.dispose(); //УБИЛИ ОКНО
                System.gc(); //НА ВСЯКИЙ
                //

                try {
                    Thread.sleep(1000);
                } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                }

                //КРУГ 2, ПОЛУЧАЕМ ССЫЛКУ НА ФРЕЙМ КОТОРЫЙ УБИТ, И ПОКАЗЫВАЕМ ЕГО ФРЕЙМ)
                wind = Window.getOwnerlessWindows();
                a = 0;
                max = wind.length;

                System.out.println("Ссылки на фреймы после уничтожения");
                while(a!=max){
                    System.out.println(wind[a].getClass().getCanonicalName());
                    ((JFrame)wind[a]).setTitle(((JFrame)wind[a]).getTitle().concat("КРУГ 2"));
                    wind[a].setVisible(true);
                    a = a + 1;
                }
                //В ИТОГЕ ДОЛЖНО ПОЛУЧИТСЯ TEST, КРУГ1, КРУГ2 В TITLE (и мы знаем сколько наш фрейм прошел кругов)в видимом убитом окне)
            }
        }).start();

    }

}
```

Comment: Последнее предложение непонятно. Можете переформулировать?

Comment: @Денис Котляров  Уничтожьте его морально!

Comment: Вам нужно поставить слушатель и вызывать метод [dispose()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Window.html#dispose()). А насчёт ссылок так и не понял.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow ахаха точно. Только так

Comment: Вызвал dispose, всеравно в Window.getOwnerlessWindows() остается еще рабочий класс Window

Comment: Окно закрылось? Может Сборщик мусора ещё не вызвался?

Comment: А как сборщик мусора влезет в массив Window[] в котором содержатся не null классы всех Window, даже после dispose?

Comment: Window[] wind = Window.getOwnerlessWindows();

Comment: Приведите, пожалуйста, минимальный компилируемый код.

Comment: Код привел, жду ответа, оригинальный код ожидает ответа на пример код.

Comment: `dispose` не убивает окно. что оно точно с ним делает, то написано в javadoc. А ссылка на окно держится в методе main: `final JFrame frame` - он никуда не девается и cg не чистится до самого окончания работы программы  Переделайте программку, чтобы не держала ссылок на окошки. Наверно так.

Comment: Как я переделаю программу? Если стандарт Java.Awt сам держит ссылки на окошки, и его метод dispose не помогает.

Comment: Даже по моему примеру видно, я не обращаюсь к JFrame, а обращаюсь к функции которую мне предоставляет AWT

Answer (score 0):

```
frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
```

если надо сразу закрыть приложение

```
frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
```

но gc его не очистит т.к. есть ссылка на этот объект, надо его отвязать от переменной

```
frame = null;
```